# Extract subdomain from URL using regexp in Golang

Tags: regex, go, subdomain

In the code sample below, I use regex to extract the subdomain name from a given URL. This sample works, but I don't think I've done it correctly at the point where I compile the regex, mainly where I insert the 'virtualHost' variable. Any suggestions?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

var (
    virtualHost string
    domainRegex *regexp.Regexp
)

func extractSubdomain(host string) string {
    matches := domainRegex.FindStringSubmatch(host)
    if matches != nil && len(matches) > 1 {
        return matches[1]
    }
    return ""
}

func init() {
    // virtualHost = os.GetEnv("VIRTUAL_HOST")
    virtualHost = "login.localhost:3000"

    domainRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`^(?:https?://)?([-a-z0-9]+)(?:\.` + virtualHost + `)*$`)
}

func main() {
    // host := req.host
    host := "http://acme.login.localhost:3000"

    if result := extractSubdomain(host); result != "" {
        fmt.Printf("Subdomain detected: %s\n", result)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("No subdomain detected")
}
```

Comment: Don't use a regex. Use the `url` package to parse the URL. Then just split on period.

Comment: Just split on period.. ah yes.. please read the RFC before you suggest .....

Comment: An alternative option without using regex is [go-tld](https://github.com/jpillora/go-tld) but this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`url`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/) package has a function [`parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) that allows you to parse an URL. The parsed [`URL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) instance has a method [`Hostname`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Hostname) which will return you the hostname.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://login.localhost:3000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(u.Hostname())
}
```

Output:

```
login.localhost
```

See https://play.golang.com/p/3R1TPyk8qck

*Update:*

My previous answer only dealt with parsing the host name. Since then I have been using the following library to parse the domain suffix from the host name. Once you have that, it is simple to strip the domain and leave only the subdomain prefix.

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix

I have found that it can be a bit tricky to exactly identify the difference between subdomain and host, without a little help first from this package that can identify common suffixes. For instance, internally we may have a domain coming from a kubernetes ingress:

```
foo.bar.host.kube.domain.com.au
```

The host is "host" and the subdomain is "foo.bar". Even with the help of the publicsuffix library it won't know that "kube" is part of the internal domain components. So you have to add some more of your own hinting to match.

Comment: I dont know why this is marked as the answer. It gives you the full hostname not the subdomain as questioned. Its not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've used

```golang
func getSubdomain(r *http.Request) string {
    //The Host that the user queried.
    host := r.URL.Host
    host = strings.TrimSpace(host)
    //Figure out if a subdomain exists in the host given.
    hostParts := strings.Split(host, ".")

    fmt.Println("host parts",hostParts)

    lengthOfHostParts := len(hostParts)

    // scenarios
    // A. site.com  -> length : 2
    // B. www.site.com -> length : 3
    // C. www.hello.site.com -> length : 4

    if lengthOfHostParts == 4 {
        return strings.Join([]string{hostParts[1]},"") // scenario C
    }
    
    if lengthOfHostParts == 3 { // scenario B with a check
        subdomain := strings.Join([]string{hostParts[0]},"")
        
        if subdomain == "www" {
            return ""
        } else {
            return subdomain
        }
    }

    return "" // scenario A
}
```